# Strange shadows in 2.8 rendering with Eevee

Tags: error, eevee-render-engine

When I render my image with Eevee, I have strange blocky, dotty shadows that appear in the image. If I zoom in very, very close in render preview they disappear. See below images for an example. Does anyone know what is going on here? Shall I report this bug to blender, or is this a modeling issue by me? (I'm brand new, hence the doughnut scene)

[image]

Zoomed in:

[image]

Super close:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the error. Having multiple light sources with contact shadows on appears to be the issue, I just toggled around until I had one primary light source with contact shadows on. Cross contacting generated these blips.

Comment: Very very interesting, thank you for sharing